# Pipenv is doing nothing

Tags: python, pipenv

System: Win 10 x64

Python: 2.7.18 x64

Pip list:

> appdirs                       1.4.4
>  astroid                       1.6.6
>  backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.1
>  bottle                        0.12.18
>  certifi                       2020.6.20
>  cffi                          1.14.1
>  chardet                       3.0.4
>  colorama                      0.4.3
>  conan                         1.20.5
>  configparser                  4.0.2
>  contextlib2                   0.6.0.post1
>  deprecation                   2.0.7
>  distlib                       0.3.1
>  distro                        1.1.0
>  enum34                        1.1.10
>  fasteners                     0.15
>  filelock                      3.0.12
>  future                        0.18.2
>  futures                       3.3.0
>  idna                          2.10
>  importlib-metadata            1.7.0
>  importlib-resources           3.0.0
>  isort                         4.3.21
>  Jinja2                        2.11.2
>  lazy-object-proxy             1.5.1
>  MarkupSafe                    1.1.1
>  mccabe                        0.6.1
>  monotonic                     1.5
>  node-semver                   0.6.1
>  packaging                     20.4
>  patch-ng                      1.17.1
>  pathlib2                      2.3.5
>  pep8                          1.7.1
>  pip                           19.2.3
>  pipenv                        2020.8.13
>  pluginbase                    0.7
>  pycparser                     2.20
>  pygit2                        0.28.2
>  Pygments                      2.5.2
>  PyJWT                         1.7.1
>  pylint                        1.9.5
>  pyparsing                     2.4.7
>  python-dateutil               2.8.1
>  PyYAML                        5.3.1
>  requests                      2.24.0
>  scandir                       1.10.0
>  setuptools                    41.2.0
>  singledispatch                3.4.0.3
>  six                           1.15.0
>  tqdm                          4.48.2
>  typing                        3.7.4.3
>  urllib3                       1.25.10
>  virtualenv                    20.0.30
>  virtualenv-clone              0.5.4
>  wrapt                         1.12.1
>  zipp                          1.2.0

Anytime I try to run `pipenv install` or `pipenv install --dev` nothing happens, no crash, no error, no stucking for ever, just a return to the command prompt.

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: Try doing virtualenv

Comment: Yeah virtualenv is working but my company framework is with pipenv so life is not as simple as it could be. Actually, I forcing ditching pipenv for poetry but we do not live in a world where I can do a magic trick and change everything like that.
Anyway, it seems that it's related to python x64, seems to be working with the x86 version, could it that ?

Comment: Yeah sometimes some librares don't work with the 32-bit version. Make sure that youv'e updated

Comment: Yeah sometimes some librares don't work with the 32-bit version. Make sure that youv'e updated